# How to Order By Dynamic value via Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm building an asp.net mvc app using Entity Framework, and I'm trying to order by a list. By a dynamic changed name, according to the name exists in the database.

```
bids = bids.OrderBy(s => s.PublisherName);
```

and the object:

```
public string PublisherName { get { db.Publishers.Find(pubid).Name; } }
```

But I'm getting an exception:

> The specified type member 'PublisherName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

What can I do? And how I can make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

`db.Publishers.Find(pubid).Name;` is neither  initializer nor entity member, nor navigation property.

One possible way is to bring it on memory with [AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
bids = bids.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.PublisherName);
```

This will work perfectly as long as bids is small list of objects.

Comment: So long as `bids` is already a filtered (small) list of objects, that's a good idea. Never do this, though: `context.Bids.AsEnumerable()...`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Bid`and `Publisher` are related, right? Maybe this will help you

```
var bids = from t in context.Bids
           let u = t.Publishers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == pubid)
           orderby u.Name
           select t;
```

Untested code, not sure if it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

When using Entity Framework via LINQ, all of the properties in the linq statement are translated in to SQL.  EF only natively understands simple properties.  It doesn't understand how to translate properties that contain actual code logic, which is what is causing the error you are seeing.  The simplest way to fix this is to do the sort client side, outside of entity framework.  The usual way to do this is to call `.ToList` on the unsorted result, and then sort the resulting list, which will happen client side.